# How create logicale table with java

Tags: java

This code allows to fill matrix column per column.

I need a method which fill the matrix line per line.

This is the result of this code:

```
0: (2 , 2 )
1: (2 , 1 )
2: (2 , 0 )
3: (1 , 2 )
4: (1 , 1 )
5: (1 , 0 )
6: (0 , 2 )
7: (0 , 1 )
8: (0 , 0 )
```

---

```
public class test {

    static public int[][] combinaison(double map [],int nbr) {         
        int [][]tab=new int [((int) Math.pow(nbr, map.length))][map.length];
        int ligne=0;
        int nb=1;
        int k=0;

        for(int i=0;i<map.length;i++) {

            while(ligne<((int) Math.pow(nbr, map.length))) {

                for(int ll=(nbr-1);ll>=0;ll--) {

                    while(k<nb) {
                        tab[ligne][map.length-(i+1)]=ll;
                        k++;    
                        ligne++;
                    }
                    k=0;
                }
            } 
            ligne=0;
            nb*=nbr;
        }
        return tab;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyBinaryArray b= new MyBinaryArray() ;

        double typetab[]=new double[]{30.1,20.0};

        b.afficheSolutionPersonaliser(combinaison(typetab,3));

    }   
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from creating the method you need?

Comment: if we found the null vector . the main idea of this method  is similar to the  truth table, but this table has a vérité number , the number of columns will always equal length of  array and  The nbr is the number of max ,for instance ; if ethe  array has 2 case , nbr =4;
the result will be as following:
0: (4 ,  4 )
1: (4 ,  3 )
2: (4 ,  2 )
3: (4 ,  1 )
4: (4 ,  0 )
5: (3 ,  4 )
6: (3 ,  3 )
7: (3 ,  2 )
8: (3 ,  1 )
9: (3 ,  0 )
10: (2 ,  4 )
11: (2 ,  3 )
12: (2 ,  2 )
13: (2 ,  1 )
14: (2 ,  0 )
............
23: (0 ,  1 )
24: (0 ,  0 )